# How to use MID, RIGHT and FIND functions in Excel?

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to combine the State (NSW) and the Postal Code (2007) from cell F4 in the worksheet "Inventory", this is the text in cell F4: 310 Wattle StUltimo, 2007, NSW

What I trying to accomplish is this: NSW2007 using MID, RIGHT and FIND functions, but is giving me a headache

I tried this: =RIGHT(Inventory!F4,4) and I got so far this: NSW, what I need to get is NSW2007 so I am missing the MID (and FIND) part

thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

With Office 365:

```
=LET(
    rr,F4,
    x,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(rr,",")),
    CONCAT(INDEX(x,COUNTA(x)-{0,1})))
```

[image]

For Older versions:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(F4,",",REPT(" ",999)),999))&
    TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(F4,",",REPT(" ",999)),(LEN(F4)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F4,",",""))-1)*999,999))
```

---

If there is always only 2 `,` in the string and you want the 3rd and 2nd then we can simplify the above formula:

```
=LET(
    rr,F4,
    x,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(rr,",")),
    CONCAT(INDEX(x,{3,2})))
```

And

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(F4,",",REPT(" ",999)),999))&
    TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(F4,",",REPT(" ",999)),999,999))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following Excel text formula.
Using the text in F4: "310 Wattle StUltimo, 2007, NSW"

To get NSW2007 from the text in F4 above use the following formula.

```
=CONCAT(TRIM(MID(F4,FIND(",",F4,FIND(",",F4,1)+1)+1,LEN(F4))),TRIM(MID(F4,FIND(",",F4,1)+1,FIND(",",F4,FIND(",",F4,1)+1)-FIND(",",F4,1)-1)))
```

1. To get NSW: =MID(F4,FIND(",",F4,FIND(",",F4,1)+1)+1,LEN(F4))
2. To get 2007: =MID(F4,FIND(",",F4,1)+1,FIND(",",F4,FIND(",",F4,1)+1)-FIND(",",F4,1)-1)

Then concatenate the two: concat (formula 1 above, formula 2 above).

This formula works regardless of the spaces (or no spaces at all) before and after the commas.

Hope this helps.